# How to set the Visual Studio Code default clone directory

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do you set the default clone directory in Visual Studio Code?  After I select Git:Clone, I paste the repository URL, and then I get asked for Parent Directory.  How do I set the parent directory to a different default directory?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is an option for this in the user settings:

```
git.defaultCloneDirectory
```

### 3rd party edit

Under windows you can press `CTRL + ,` to open the user settings and enter the path to your desired directory with slashes:

```
"git.defaultCloneDirectory": "E:/yourPath/toYour/gitFolder/"
```

Comment: Windows-style path also works for me in Windows 10, Code 1.40.0: `C:\\Users\\MyName\\repos` including double backslash.

Comment: Should this say `CTRL + ,` rather than `STRG + ,`?

Comment: Yes, I've changed it. `STRG` (Steuerung) is the german translation of `CTRL`. About half of germand keyboards have printed `STRG` on that key, the other half `CTRL`.